# probability using exponential distribution

Tags: statistics

The time a student spends in the shower is an exponential random variable with a mean of 262 seconds.

Calculate the probability that a student spends an average of over 270 seconds in the shower per school day, taken over one calender year of 365 days.

I am not too sure how to answer this question. I was told we went over this in class but unfortunately I was batteling kidney stones the past 2 weeks. Please could someone walk me through a solution, I would really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, it is appropriate to use the central limit theorem. For parameter of the exponential distribution applies:

$\frac{1}{\lambda} = E(t) = 262 \Rightarrow \lambda =\frac{1}{262},\,\frac{1}{\lambda^2}= D(t) = 262^2$

The mean and variance of the sum of 365 random variables s parameter $\lambda$:

$E(t)_{365}=E\left(\frac{t_1+t_2+\cdots+x_{365}}{365}\right)=E(t)=262$

$D(t)_{365}=D\left(\frac{t_1+t_2+\cdots+x_{365}}{365}\right)=\frac{D(t)}{365}=\frac{262^2}{365}$

$\Rightarrow P(T>270)=1-P(T\le 270) \approx  1-F(270),$

F(t) = distribution function of the normal probability distribution $N(E(t)_{365},D(t)_{365})=N(262,188.066)$

$\Rightarrow P(T>270)\doteq 1-0.720 = 0.28$

---

Interest:

Exact calculation using Erlang probability distribution:
$\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{364} \frac{(270\cdot 365/262)^j}{j!}  e^{-(270\cdot 365)/262} \doteq 0.2759$

Comment: the gamma distribution should be an option too?

Comment: @SamBhatt: Yes, Erlang distribution is a special case of gamma distribution.